# How to Append to a file in a Firefox add-on?

Tags: javascript, file-io, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var iofile = require("sdk/io/file");
var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
var selection = require("sdk/selection");


function console_log(text) {
    console.log(selection.text);
}

function print(text) {
    console.log(text);
}

function dir_object(object_to_parse) {
    var name = '';
    for (name in object_to_parse) {
        print(name);
    }
}

function write_text(filename, text) {
    var fh = iofile.open(filename, 'w');
    var content = fh.read();

    dir_object(fh);

    selected_text = text + "\n";
    fh.write(selected_text);
    fh.flush();
    fh.close()
}

function select_text_handler() { 
    write_text('/tmp/foo', selection.text);
}

var widget = widgets.Widget({
    id: "scribus-link",
    label: "Scribus website",
    contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
    onClick: function() {
    }
});



selection.on('select', function () { select_text_handler(); });
```

'open' the file in 'w' and that truncates my existing file! How do i open in 'append' mode and then 'seek'?? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/io/file.htm

Comment: Is there a `"w+"` mode?

Comment: not in the docs and not when i tried.. it accepts 'w+' but after the close, when the next line is written, it writes from the start of file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `file` module of the SDK is pretty limited. When opening a file for writing it will always be truncated ([code](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/613de5ee8f5db7e81fd2d65416d8760c61a0bbd1/lib/sdk/io/file.js#L142-L144)). Also, it is uses entirely synchronous I/O on the main thread, which isn't really a good thing to do, as it will block the entire UI during the I/O.

You should probably use another mechanism via the [`chrome`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html) module. See [OS.File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread) and/or the [MDN File I/O snippets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/File_I_O#Writing_to_a_file).

Comment: Where can i find documentation on 'chrome' - every time I google i get 'Google Chrome' and not the Firefox Chrome.