# What is the Firefox/Javascript chrome module - documentation?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Every time i Google i get the Chrome browser - grr! But I'm trying to understand this:

> use another mechanism via the **chrome** module. See OS.File and/or the MDN File I/O snippets.

Where can i find documentation for this Firefox+Javascript module?
[How to Append to a file in a Firefox add-on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583711/how-to-append-to-a-file-in-a-firefox-add-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated my answer in that other question. I was talking about the SDK [`chrome` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html), which is just a way to access `Components` and with that the XPCOM services and components, so basically what every "old school" XUL add-on gets.